# Как считать данные из input в Angular 2

Tags: input, angular2, typescript

У меня есть таблица, состоящая из полей для ввода. Есть ли возможность в Angular 2 считывать данные из полей и отображать их под таблицей? На примере [image: Так выглядит таблица сейчас] вверху в каждое поле введена буква слова, которое стоит справа от таблицы. я хочу, чтобы эти буквы можно было считать и отобразить внизу таблицы одним словом. Мой код

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'part1',
  template: `
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input value="R"></td>
        <td><input value="o"></td>
        <td><input value=""></td>
        <td><input value="s"></td>
        <td><input value="e"></td>
        <td><input value="n"></td>
        <p>Rosen</p>
      </tr>
      <tr id ="check" *ngFor="let item of itemsSource">
        <td *ngFor="let item of list2"><input [(ngModel)]="value2"></td>
        {{item}}
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button>OK</button>
    <p>{{value2}}</p>

  `,
  // styleUrls: ['app/part1/part1.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class Part1Component implements OnInit {
  public itemsSource: string[];
  list: string[] = [];
  list2: string[] = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemsSource = this.dataService.getData();
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте принцип работы с формами в ангулар 2. Там большое колличество вариантов.... Можно использовать name можно задавать локальную переменную в шаблоне #

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте написать директиву. Повешайте её на `<tr>`. Пусть эта директива пробегает по всем дочерним элементам `<td>`, получая их значения и выводит в нужное место. Это на вскидку. При более точном описании задачи, можно точнее помочь.

#### Вариант номер 2

Смотрите, можно сделать так, создать компоненту, в компоненте есть `<input [(ngModel)] = "value">`. В теле компоненты объявим переменную как `@Input() value: string`. Эта компонента будет динамически добавляться, согласно вашим условиям. Ссылку на вновь созданный объект(компоненту) сохранить где либо в массиве или ещё как. Далее по какому либо событию можно пробегать по данному сохранённому списку и выбирать данные значения. Обращаясь к полю `value` либо в компоненте добавить оповещалку родителя об изменениях в дочерних элементах, что позволить всегда знать, что введено. Нечто аналогичное мне удалось провернуть в своём проекте, прочитав [статью](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Директиву? Angular2? Пробегать по tr? Что-то тут совсем не то...

Comment: [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), есть идеи получше? Готов выслушать :)

Comment: @SergeyRogachev Сергей, спасибо за ответ, посмотрела документацию, похоже так не получится...если более конкретно, то мне надо создать такую таблицу вводов, как на примере. Чтобы была возможность вводить буквы и проверять, нужные ли были введены. Как проверить - я уже написала алгоритм, он работает. Но для это алгоритма, мне нужно собрать буквы с каждой строки в array of arrays, которая будет выглядить так [['Ro_sen'] , ['Planeten']]. То есть, есть ли способ считать данные с каждого input и положить в array?... Вот пример http://savepic.ru/14371966.png